# Grouped checkboxes in Symfony / twig

Tags: symfony, checkbox, doctrine, twig

I have 2 entities: Projects and Categories. I have a ManyToMany relation between these two.
The Categories has ManytoOne relation with the entity "industry" 
At this moment, there is no direct relation between Projects and industry and I would like to keep this like so, for further search functionality. So in the category table, the list includes categories from all industries.

When I build the form to edit the project (using the form widget), I have a list of checkboxes representing all the categories listed in my category table.

I would like to group the category choices by industry. How can this be done on the form layout only? How can I extract the industry value from the twig widget form data and group the checkboxes by the industry entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Leevi,

I could not find how to implement the suggestion above using both industry and category related entities... I finally found this way of going around the issue, tell me if there is a simpler way, but this works perfect now.

**This is my form in the controller**

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($project)
            ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
                'class'    => 'ACMEProjectBundle:Category',
                'property' => 'name',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                ->getForm();
```

I also pass to the rendered form the array of industries which has each a list of related categories

```
$industries = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ACMEProjectBundle:Industry')->findall();
```

**In the form.html.twig template**

```
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        <form method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {% for industry in industries %}
            <h4>{{industry.name}}</h4>
            <ul class="unstyled">
                {% for category in industry.categories %}
                    {% set key = category.id %}
                    <li>{{ form_widget(form.categories[key]) }}{{category.name}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
        {{form_rest(form)}}
```

Which gives me the wanted results.

Comment: This was a lifesaver! Thank you very much for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will be enough direction without giving you exact code examples :).

You'll have to setup your form with an expanded, multiple, entity field like so:

```
<?php

// src/Acme/ProjectBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
namespace Acme\ProjectBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Acme\ProjectBundle\Entity\Project;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        // create a project and give it some dummy data for this example
        $project = new Project();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($project)
            ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'group_by' => 'industry.title'
            ))
            ->add('save', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        return $this->render('AcmeProjectBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

The group_by parameter groups the options based on the property path:

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by

Now `group_by` renders a select tag but you should be able to override that with a custom twig theme or manually in the template.

Given the form above you can access the choices in `{{ form.categories.vars.choices }}` and iterate over them manually.

See: `{% block choice_widget_collapsed %}` in `form_div_layout.html.twig` to see how the select box is rendered.

Here's some more information of form theming: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622586/grouping-checkboxes-in-symfony2

Comment: Thanks M. Graham, I shall try this.